# How do you create an array with jQuery from an input's value?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am able to create an array using the following code below. The issue with this is that, what if an individual enters 50 tacos. I am afraid the browser will go through an entire list looking for the rel attribute.

```
<ul id="taco">
   <li rel="19">other html goes here</li>
   <li rel="50">other html goes here</li>
   <li rel="1535">other html goes here</li>
   <li rel="875">other html goes here</li>
</ul>

$("#taco li").each(function() {
   $tacoOrder.push($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

So, I was thinking of putting the taco order values in an input box. For example my code looks like this.

```
<input value="19, 50, 1535, 875">
```

I want to take the value from this input and create an array. Is this even possible, or is it better to do an each function?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. `$('#tacosValue').val().split(',').map(Number)` Replace `#tacosValue` with your selector.

Answer (score 1):

This can be one solution:

```
var liObj  = $("#taco li");
//Convert the list to an Array
var arr = jQuery.makeArray(liObj);
```